# QT 5.13.0 Open ssl notworking mingw 7.3.0

Tags: qt, openssl, mingw

I am trying to use QNetworkAccessManager with SSL but it is not working.

```
qDebug() << "Support SSL:  " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl()
            << "\nLib Version Number: " <<         QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber()
        << "\nLib Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()
        << "\nLib Build Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber()
        << "\nLib Build Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

Result is:

```
Support SSL:   false 
Lib Version Number:  0 
Lib Version String:  "" 
Lib Build Version Number:  269488175 
Lib Build Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019"
```

I have tried to install `openssl openssl-1.1.1c.tar.gz` from https://www.openssl.org/source/
But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html

> `QString QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()` Returns the version
>   string of the SSL library in use. Note that this is the version of the
>   library in use at run-time not compile time. If no SSL support is
>   available then this will return an empty value.
>
> `QString QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` Returns the
>   version string of the SSL library in use at compile time. If no SSL
>   support is available then this will return an empty value.

So you have Qt with the OpenSSL, but you have not OpenSSL loaded correctly run-time.

You could use third party OpenSSL related binaries https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries (or compile manually from the https://www.openssl.org/source/)

After installing, check that OpenSSL binaries are available for your application (added to the `PATH`), and you need to provide the OpenSSL binaries for your deployed application.

OpenSSL x64 v1.1 binaries are `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this other reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58382414/2480398) downloading: https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/openssl/1.1.1g and made sure the PATH binary location precedes System32 (ie. Windows). Everything worked fine. QT does document this:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#ssl

One thing I noticed looking into this, QT does not like the cygwin version of OpenSSL (Windows apps rarely do). However if your using this legitimately(ie. non-test/dev) I would suggest you master your own installation of OpenSSL instead of relying on thirdparty compilations.