# How to deploy QT application with OpenSSL

Tags: qt, deployment, openssl

When I run the application from the directory that it was built in, there is no problem but when I try to run the application from another directory, after carrying the exe file in it, OpenSSL does not work.

I copied **libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll** and **libssl-1_1-x64.dll** files in the same directory, windeployqt takes care of the other dlls. What could be missing? If it's necessary, how do I make the configuration for the runtime?

Comment: Did you check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235510/qt-5-13-0-open-ssl-notworking-mingw-7-3-0/58382414#58382414

Comment: If your OS is **windows** you should install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: It is windows and I'm not able to run openssl command from command line, it gives me error. Tried re-installing but didn't work either. Does it have to work when I'm deploying an application?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL libraries are precompiled with Qt via Qt Maintenance Tool. Because it's a C library it doesn't matter if is MSVC or MingW compiler. This little guide should work:

1. Install OpenSSL from Maintenance Tool.

[image]

2. Independently of your compiler, go to C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\bin (if you have 64 bits application).
3. Copy libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll and paste in your release or debug application executable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but no matter from where I copied these two dlls, it doesn't work. Could it be related to my Windows version of openssl because it's an older version and I haven't been able to update it?

Comment: Mmm. What're your windows build? Qt version? Compiler? OpenSSL version?

Comment: It's Windows 10, Qt 6.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.1k. I solved the problem, apparently there are 3 dlls inside QT plugins directory, within tls directory. I copied this tls directory next to my exe and now I can deploy with OpenSSL.

Comment: Qt 6.2. Maybe something has changed that needs a third dll. The below short guide is for >5.15.5. Good catch.

Comment: @jupi can you provide the path and names of the other dll(s)? Was it these? qcertonlybackend.dll, qopensslbackend.dll, qschannelbackend.dll? From C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\plugins\tls.

Comment: @Edward yes it's the right path. you are supposed to copy and paste it as the "tls" folder next to your executable, not the DLLs one by one